# Post Request Returns 400 Bad Request after Publishing

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, jwt, bad-request

I'm totally stuck after saw that my POST method returns 400 Bad Request. Strange part is, they worked fine on Local. When I publish my API project and deploy it to our test server, POST methods stops work.

This is my `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>                                               
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />    
    </configSections>                                                
    <appSettings></appSettings>                                       
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />                          
    </system.web>                                               
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" /> <!-- In order to fix 405 Error on Put method -->
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." 
                 verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"  
                 type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
        <!--<security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <verbs>
                    <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
                </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>-->                                             
    </system.webServer>                                                  
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"  
                                  publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>                                                  
</runtime>                                                    
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>                                                 
</system.codedom>                                            
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="XDataContext" connectionString="data source=XXX.XXX.XX.XX;initial catalog=X;user id=X;password=X;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />                    
</connectionStrings>                                          
</configuration>
```

I have tried the suggested solutions on here [IIS hosted WCF Service return HTTP 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855068/iis-hosted-wcf-service-return-http-400-bad-request) and here [ASP.NET Web API "400 Bad Request" on POST Request When Deploying to Test Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571183/asp-net-web-api-400-bad-request-on-post-request-when-deploying-to-test-server) , but none of them worked in my case unfortunatelly.

One last note is, Error Message on Fiddler is also totally empty when I receive this error.

```
{"Message":""}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I comment out security tag as they also didn't solve my issue.

**EDIT 2:**

Below is the method which returns bad request on server, but works fine on local:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostLogin(LoginWM loginWM)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_userTokenManager.CheckUser(loginWM))
            {
                _userTokenManager.SaveToken(loginWM.Email, loginWM.Password);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, _userTokenManager.PublishToken(loginWM.Email, loginWM.Password));
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new Exception("User not found."));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And what I'm sending (in JSON format) are as below:

```
{"Email":"ozgur@gmail.com","Password":"oa123"}
```

Here is the class I used for the above JSON:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XX.XX.Model.WebModel
{
    public class LoginWM
    {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you logging exceptions, errors etc on the server? You might want to check the log files, if any.

Comment: Could you please post a specific example? e.g. A payload that you try to POST and the method that should respond to this POST. Thanks !

Comment: @Christos I shared an example

Comment: @RaZzLe Also share the code of `LoginWM` class. Also, ensure that connectionstring of database is valid. `_userTokenManager` is injected in the controller via constructor?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I'm now sharing LoginWM class too. By saying "ensure that connectionstring of database is valid" you mean the <connectionStrings> part in my Web.config? If so, I am sure as it works fine on Local. And about your last question, yes, its injected via constructor method `public UserTokenController()
        {
            _userTokenManager = new UserTokenManager();
        }`

Comment: @RaZzLe Does your test server also connects to the same sql server instance that you are using on your localhost? Also, try changing the line `return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.ToString());` changed `ex.Message` to ex.ToString()

Comment: @MohsinMehmood thank you very much for your reminder about that change, at least now I can trully see what the problem is. It says `IDX12401: Expires: '[PII is hidden]' must be after NotBefore: '[PII is hidden]'`
This controller issues a Json Web Token under normal circumstances. I searched for this `IDX12401` and saw its related JWT issues. I will dig up more

Comment: (Still can't figure out why its generating a successful token on local but not on test server)

Comment: `UserTokenManager` class interacts with database and validates user? I again recommend to verify your database connection string and ensure that you can connect to database server from your test server using the credentials you haave specified in your web.config